# Creating SSRS report in Visual Studio but can't see any data in preview

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50qfz.jpg)

I am creating my first SSRS report in Visual Studio but I couldn't see any data when I preview. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how you think we can help with that little information.

Comment: You can hit the green arrow refresh icon in the report toolbar to determine if it is a cache issue. VS will cache data in ReportName.rdl.data files until you change a data definition property, i.e. modify a field/parameter or change the underlying data source or query definition. The green arrow will always trigger a hard refresh and fetch new data from the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font style and size, it should work, it worked for me.